# Advise on php mail() function, Code Igniter and Mandrill

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I can't find a right answer to my questions and am at this right moment not able to test this things.
My question can be split in to two sub questions:

1. When I send a email in Code Igniter and added a SMTP server, a username etc etc (mandrill credentials), is Code Igniter using the PHP Mail() function to send this email?
2. In case that sub 1 is true, how can I prevent using the PHP mail() function and still be able to send emails via a tool like Mandrill?

For a little clarification, I want to globally (php.ini) disable the php mail() function. I have a VPS which seems to be hacked. Its sending out like 1 million emails in 24 hours, and all of them go through the mail() function. I want this one to be put down so I can evaluate all the domains on the server, because afaik all domains are infected.

So, please some advise! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to question one:

If you set up the SMTP server settings right, CodeIgniter will indeed send the mail without using the PHP Mail function.

It will use socket communication to send the email directly to the SMTP server. You can see this in: `system/libraries/Email.php`

Answer to question two:

If you set other services up to send mail via SMTP as well, there should be no problems in sending email from them.